# How do I recursively set a folder and all of its subfolders and files to drwxrwxrwx

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do you I set the option "drwxrwxrwx" for a certain folder and all of its subfolders and all files in all subdirs?

I want to set these files and folders to the maximum allowed for my user.

Thank you!

Comment: sudo chmod -r 777 folder_path (7 means 111 which is read write execute bits set to one)

Comment: I think Super User would be a better place for this. It has been asked [before](https://superuser.com/questions/1325221/linux-how-to-recursively-chmod-a-folder) though.

Comment: @BrokenFrog When I type "sudo chmod - 777 mypath", it says "cannot access '777': No such file or directory".

Comment: use `sudo chmod -R 777 folder_path`

Comment: @王万鹏 Thank you! Can you make your comment the answer?

Comment: @tmighty i think you ommited recursive flag which is r

Comment: @BrokenFrog, I did type it as you suggested. However, it didn't like "r". It wanted "R" instead.

Comment: @tmighty `sudo chmod - 777 mypath` it seemed you forgot about r but yeah you are right i checked the man page for chmod the recursive flag was capital R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod -R 777 folder_path`

If there is a permission error to the folder, use `sudo chmod -R 777 folder_path`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, couldn't find simple one liner to change permissions of all subfolders and files in the specified folder.. And just went out of my head with this and it worked like a charm
so let's say my folder was `xampp htdocs` folder at `/opt/lampp/htdocs`

(In my case I needed this:)

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /opt/lampp/htdocs/*/*
```

I think this might work as a solution for this problem:

```
sudo chmod -r 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/*/*
```

First time I only used `/opt/lamp/htdocs/*` but then it just changed permision to everything in htdocs file but not the subfolders.. `/opt/lamp/htdocs/*/*` did the thing for me.